# How to implement IReactiveNotifyPropertyChanged on a base class that alreay implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: inotifypropertychanged, reactiveui

Currently I have this generic implementation by inheriting from an existing base class that provides `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I cannot change this base class, but I want to provide the property change notifications also as an `Observable` so I implement the `IReactiveNotifyPropertyChanged` interface as well.

I find the code below (obtained through a process of trial and error) to be quite involved and was wondering if this could be done in a more simple, concise manner.

Also, I'm struggling to come up with ideas to suppress notifications. Any thoughts?

```
public class MyReactiveClass<T> : PropertyChangeNotifyingBaseClass<T>, IReactiveNotifyPropertyChanged<T> 
    where T : class
{
    public MyReactiveClass()
    {
        Changed = Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>
            (
            t => PropertyChanged += t, // add handler
            t => PropertyChanged -= t  // remove handler
            // conversion from EventPattern to ReactivePropertyChangedEventArgs
            ).Select(ev => new ReactivePropertyChangedEventArgs<T>(ev.Sender as T, ev.EventArgs.PropertyName));

        Changing = Observable.FromEventPattern<System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangingEventHandler, PropertyChangingEventArgs>
            (
            t => PropertyChanging += t, // add handler
            t => PropertyChanging -= t  // remove handler
            // conversion from EventPattern to ReactivePropertyChangedEventArgs
            ).Select(ev => new ReactivePropertyChangedEventArgs<T>(ev.Sender as T, ev.EventArgs.PropertyName));
    }

    public IObservable<IReactivePropertyChangedEventArgs<T>> Changing { get; }
    public IObservable<IReactivePropertyChangedEventArgs<T>> Changed { get; }

    public IDisposable SuppressChangeNotifications()
    {
        // how to deal with suppression of change notifications?!
        return Disposable.Empty; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written the shortest possible piece of code to implement `Changed` and `Changing` observables, what do you want to achieve more? :)

Since you need `Changed`, `Changing`, `SuppressChangeNotifications`, and maybe in a month you will want something else of `ReactiveObject`, the best solution would be to use `ReactiveObject` as base class.
But if you can't do that, I will suggest you to download the source code of **reactiveui** and take just the pieces of code that you need:
https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI

You better don't implement certain features by yourself. The creators of the framework have dealt with many bugs and issues so their code is certainly more solid of what I or you can produce by ourselves (unless we're genius).